# Symfony 2: LiipDoctrineCacheBundle not found in AppKernel

Tags: symfony, bundle

I've installed this bundle [LiipDoctrineCacheBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipDoctrineCacheBundle/) in *vendor\bundles\* folder of my website.

Then, as usual, I added in *autoload.php* a new entry in the array namespace:

`'Liip' => __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles',`

And I registered this new bundle in the bundles' array of *AppKernel.php*:

`new Liip\DoctrineCacheBundle\LiipDoctrineCacheBundle(),`

But weirdly I get this error message:

`Fatal error: Class 'liip\DoctrineCacheBundle\LiipDoctrineCacheBundle' not found in C:\workspace\LHN\app\AppKernel.php on line 26`

It's like if Symfony cannot retrieve the bundle in the nameSpace...

So I've tried by changing the case of the bundle key: `'Liip'`==> `'liip'`

And I've also tried with the fully path location: 
`__DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles'` ==> `C:\workspace\mySite\vendor\bundles`

Any idea?

Thks

Symfony: 2.0.9
Liip bundle: master

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Laurynas's comment I understood my problem: the source bundle path was wrong 
`vendor\bundles\liip\LiipDoctrineCacheBundle`

instead of

`vendor\bundles\Liip\DoctrineCacheBundle`

The origin of this issue is that I made a mistake in the *deps* file (where the git *location*, the *version* and the *target* directory are defined) by setting the *target* property to */bundles/liip/LiipDoctrineCacheBundle* instead of to */bundles/Liip/DoctrineCacheBundle*.

My bad... ;-)

Correct dep block:

```
[LiipDoctrineCacheBundle]
 git=https://github.com/liip/LiipDoctrineCacheBundle.git
 target=/bundles/Liip/DoctrineCacheBundle
 version=master
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using the wrong name for the bundle class.
i think it should be

```
new Liip\LiipDoctrineCacheBundle\LiipDoctrineCacheBundle()
```

or

```
new liip\LiipDoctrineCacheBundle\LiipDoctrineCacheBundle()
```

not sure if the first "L" is capital or not in your vendor/bundles/ source